# Error in displaying chart in Django with chartit

Tags: javascript, jquery, python, django, highcharts

I have an application for which I am trying to display a simple chart of number of proposals per country. I am using pivotchart in chartit as explained [here](https://github.com/chartit/django-chartit)

I have a model like this

```
class Proposal(models.Model):
org = models.CharField(max_length=200)
country = models.CharField(max_length=100)
recdate = models.DateField(blank=False)
subdate = models.DateField(blank=False)
status = models.CharField(choices = stat_val, max_length=20)
```

and as explained in the chartit GitHub, I have added this to views

```
from django.db.models import Count
from chartit import PivotDataPool, PivotChart
from django.shortcuts import render_to_response

def proposal_pivot_chart_view(request):
# Step 1: Create a PivotDataPool with the data we want to retrieve.
proposalpivotdata = PivotDataPool(
    series=[{
        'options': {
            'source': Proposal.objects.all(),
            'categories': ['country'],
        },
        'terms': {
            'countprop': Count('id'),
        }
    }]
)

# Step 2: Create the PivotChart object
chart1 = PivotChart(
    datasource=proposalpivotdata,
    series_options=[{
        'options': {
            'type': 'column',
            'stacking': True
        },
        'terms': ['countprop']
    }],
    chart_options={
        'title': {
            'text': 'Proposals by Countries'
        },
        'xAxis': {
            'title': {
                'text': 'Country'
            }
        }
    }
)

# Step 3: Send the PivotChart object to the template.
return render_to_response({'chart1': chart1})
```

and I have created a template like this

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>
    {% load staticfiles %}
    {% load static %}
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css' %}" >
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'bootstrap/css/light-bootstrap-dashboard.css' %}" >
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'bootstrap/css/animate.min.css' %}">
    <link href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.2.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:400,700,300' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'bootstrap/css/pe-icon-7-stroke.css' %}">
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.1/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="{{ MEDIA_URL }}highcharts/js/highcharts.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    {% load chartit %}
    {{ rainpivchart|load_charts:"container" }}
</head>
<body>
    {% include "proposal/main-banner.html"%}
<div id='container'></div>
<a href = "{% url 'list' %}" style="float: center; color: black;"><button>Back to Proposal List</button></a>
</body>
</html>
```

But there is some problem and I am getting error

```
TemplateDoesNotExist at /chart1/
{'chart1': <chartit.charts.PivotChart object at 0x046ADF30>}
Request Method:
GET
Request URL:
http://127.0.0.1:8000/chart1/
Django Version:
1.10.6
Exception Type:
TemplateDoesNotExist
Exception Value:
{'chart1': <chartit.charts.PivotChart object at 0x046ADF30>}
Exception Location:
C:\Users\Parag\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\django-1.10.6-py3.6.egg\django\template\loader.py in get_template, line 25
Python Executable:
C:\Users\Parag\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\python.exe
Python Version:
3.6.0
Python Path:
['C:\\Users\\Parag\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python36-32\\Lib\\site-packages\\Django-1.10.6-py3.6.egg\\django\\bin\\myoffice',
 'C:\\Users\\Parag\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python36-32\\python36.zip',
 'C:\\Users\\Parag\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python36-32\\DLLs',
 'C:\\Users\\Parag\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python36-32\\lib',
 'C:\\Users\\Parag\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python36-32',
 'C:\\Users\\Parag\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python36-32\\lib\\site-packages',
 'C:\\Users\\Parag\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python36-32\\lib\\site-packages\\django-1.10.6-py3.6.egg']
Server time:
Tue, 18 Apr 2017 16:09:08 +0400
Template-loader postmortem
Django tried loading these templates, in this order:
Using engine django:
django.template.loaders.app_directories.Loader: C:\Users\Parag\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\django-1.10.6-py3.6.egg\django\contrib\admin\templates\{'chart1': <chartit.charts.PivotChart object at 0x046ADF30>} (Source does not exist)
django.template.loaders.app_directories.Loader: C:\Users\Parag\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\django-1.10.6-py3.6.egg\django\contrib\auth\templates\{'chart1': <chartit.charts.PivotChart object at 0x046ADF30>} (Source does not exist)
django.template.loaders.app_directories.Loader: C:\Users\Parag\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\highcharts\templates\{'chart1': <chartit.charts.PivotChart object at 0x046ADF30>} (Source does not exist)
```

Comment: I tried changing the render line like this `return render_to_response('proposal/chart1',{chart1})` but still getting same error. In templates tried Django is showing **django.template.loaders.app_directories.Loader: C:\Users\Parag\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\django-1.10.6-py3.6.egg\django\contrib\admin\templates\proposal\chart1 (Source does not exist)** but chart1.html template file is in same location